# Using This for Forms - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble writing a form validator script in jQuery. In my code, if an input field is empty when the submit button is clicked, I want that input's border to become red. I am trying to use `this` to achieve the desired effect, but it seems to be selecting my button instead of my input. Here's the relevant code:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  if($('input').val() == '') {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
  }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you read the code, it makes sense. You're saying "I'm a button; when you click me, and this other input is blank, make my (this) border red".

Answer (score 2):

Do not bind on the button click but on the form submit.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  var empty = $('input',this).filter(function(){return this.value == ''});

  if (empty.length){
       empty.css('border-color', 'red');
       return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers in jQuery run in the context of the object you attach them to.  Hence, inside your `function`, `this` will always refer to the `button`.

If you want to change the style of the input, you need to target the input:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  if($('input').val() == '') {
    $('input').css('border-color', 'red');
  }
});
```

However, be aware that `$('input')` will actually select *every input on the page* regardless of type or where it exists.  You might want to think about a different way to target a specific input, such as by ID or Class.

### Edit:

To target empty inputs only, try the selector `$("input[value='']")`

Comment: Note that this will change all `input` elements' borders to red, not just the ones with no value.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this already. Is there a way to only style empty inputs?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yeah, I mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: @H.Allen Play around with it.  Keep your console open and try different selectors.  It's the best way to learn how they work.  `$('input')`, `$('input[name=test]')`, `$('input[type=number]')` (I may have placed quotes incorrectly etc)

Comment: @alex this does not work. It only checks if the ***attribute*** value is present and empty. It does not check the `value` ***property*** which reflect the live state of the input element.